# How to manually create Shared Static Durables in TIBCO EMS

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

Does anyone know how to manually create shared static durable subscriptions in TIBCO EMS?

There is no checkbox for "shared" in the **web interface** of tibco:
[image]

I also tried it with **GEMS**, but there was no option either:

[image]

The only way i could create shared durables was by starting up my application and let it be created automatically. But then the durable is not `static`

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found was to use the CLI of TIBCO EMS or to edit the durables.conf:
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.6.0/doc/html/GUID-01D08BD3-6A07-4A11-A809-21436D479391.html

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.5.1/doc/html/GUID-65F9AC62-C78E-411D-A7B0-50485812CE71.html

However it is recommended to use the CLI:

> To configure durable subscriptions in this file, we recommend using
> the create durable command in the tibemsadmin tool; see **create**
> **durable**.
>
> If the create durable command detects an existing dynamic durable
> subscription with the same topic and name, it promotes it to a static
> subscription, and writes a specification to the file **durables.conf**.